# cellForRowAtIndexPath: returns nil/ app crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My app has a table view with Dynamic cells. The cells are instances of a custom `UITableViewCell` class. Populating the table is working fine. At some point in the app i need to determine what cell is being shown on screen. I'm using this function to determine the cell being viewed in the `scrollViewDidScroll` method. The cells height is large so I came up with an equation to determine the `index` of the cell being shown like this:

```
int index = (((int)scrollView.contentOffset.y)+250)/566;

NSLog(@"%@", [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:1]]);
```

When I run the app, it returns null! I searched on Stack Overflow for such a problem and i couldn't find an answer. How can i return the cell?

Comment: What output are you exactly expecting ? Is it the index of the cell that is being viewed or something else ?

Comment: I'm expecting to return the cell at a certain index path (hence the NSLog above)

Comment: Why don't you use `indexPathOfRowAtPoint` in order to determine the index path at a specific point instead of reading the scrollview's `contentOffset`? It seems a bit unsafe. You can also always get the visible cells straight away by calling `_tableview.visibleCells`

Comment: just wondering about `inSection:1`. how many sections do you have? also... what happens when you do the same but for `inSection:0`? but... then again, what @spassas suggested is safer.

Answer (score 1):

As a general reference, I think it's pretty unsafe to read the scrollview's `contentOffset` value in order to get an index path. `UITableView` has the convenience method `indexPathOfRowAtPoint:` which can be used for that. So, to get the index path, you can use

```
CGPoint point = .... // Whatever your point is
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
```

Also you can always use `_tableView.visibleCells` to get an array with the currently visible cells.

Both these ways are much safer and will save you trouble and errors